# Can Only download ParseFiles with the same app that uploaded them

Tags: android, file-upload, parse-platform, download

I have been stuck on this for a surprisingly long time and have spent a great deal of time searching for an answer but have had no luck.

I am able to retrieve the ParseFile fine with:

```
ParseFile imageFile = parseObj.getParseFile("image");
```

Along with strings and numbers and things.

However, when I attempt to download the file's contents with:

```
imageFile.getDataInBackground(...)
```

The request always times out with a code 100 error:

```
com.parse.RarseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
```

With the cause given as:

```
"Connection refused"
```

Surprisingly though file contents can be down loaded if the file was uploaded with the same app.  Even different apps that are given the exact same application ID, client key and server address as each other are unable to download each others files, though they can download their own.  I have tested this with both Android and iOS applications.

When image files are uploaded by apps those images are visible (and downloadable) through the Parse Dashboard however only the app that uploaded the file can download it again, and no apps can download files that were uploaded by the Parse Dashboard itself.

In my app the Parse object is initialised with:

```
Parse.initialize( new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
    .applicationId("App ID")
    .clientKey("Client Key")
    .server("http://server.com:1400/service_subdir").build()
```

And the server's 'config.js' file contains:

```
config.appID = 'App ID';
config.clientKey = 'Client Key';
config.jsKey = 'Javascript Key';
```

Where "App ID" and "Client Key" are identical in both cases.

A further thing of note is that we have multiple services running on the same server and for some reason although these images are being uploaded to a specific service the files URL is given as a different service, as in, even though the server is given as:

```
"http://server.com:1400/service_subdir/"
```

The URL returned by the ParseFile is:

```
"url": "http://localhost:1400/different_service_dir/files/App ID/..._file.png"
```

And for the life of me I can't workout why.

I can (sort of) understand why "http://server.com:1400" is swapped out for "http://localhost:1400" but why "service_subdir" is changed to "different_service_dir" completely baffles me.  Even files uploaded directly from the Parse Dashboard itself when retrieved still list the "different_service_dir" in the ParseFile's URL (and won't download).  Even files uploaded by the same app (which do download), list their URL addresses with this "different_service_dir", and I am completely lost as to why.

Thanks for any help you can provide,
Slarti.

Comment: After further investigation...

If the uploading app is un-installed and re-installed again the app is no longer able to download the image files it uploaded, so this leads me to think the fact this ever worked at all was probably a caching quirk more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file to external storage, no app can read another apps internal storage - that would mean you have no security on your device. You will still need superuser access to read the file.

Comment: When you're finished with this project there are some fjords in Norway that need your attention..

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I'm not wanting to save anything to local storage.  The fact that it appears files were being stored locally by my app is but disguising the fact that it isn't receiving files from the server and if anything is an _inconvenient_ convenience.  I am wanting to store images on a Parse server and download them with my app.  This is a very common use for Parse however, for some reason it seems that although my app can 'see' the files on the server it is unable to download the data inside them.  It seems now the fact that it could 'download' files it uploaded itself is but a ruse.

Comment: And yes, I can't wait to get back to Norway.  I do love those crinkly bits ;)